# Spring Boot & RabbitMQ: How to detect when the application has re-connected to the broker

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a spring boot application acting as a producer and sending messages via RabbitMQ.
In case the broker is down, is there some kind of listener that will detect when the broker is up again in order to retry sending the failed messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not if you are only producing messages. You could add a `@Scheduled` method (and `@EnableScheduling`) that attempts to create a connection every so often and you can add a `ConnectionListener` to the connection factory which will be called when the new connection is opened.

Since the connection is shared, it won't hurt anything having this scheduled task running when the connection is already open...

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
public void tryConn() {
    try {
        this.cachingConnectionFactory.createConnection().close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

On the consumer side, the listener container will keep retrying.